# Is there a convention for accepting my own answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python) in SO. Non of the answers I got over time satisfied me, and it wasn't that important for me to start a bounty. Eventually I resolved the problem by myself, and it wasn't exactly a solution that occurred in either of the answers.

Now I had a big dilemma: What to do with the question? I have a solution, but it's sown up a lot to my special case. Should I answer my own question? If I did, should I accept my answer? Should I just close the question? Or should I do nothing.

Moreover, is there a convention about answering your own question?

*Short Notice: I eventually did answer my own question, and accepted the answer. But if the best solution would be to delete the question or the answer, I will do that.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, answer your own question.**  It is within the rule and spirit of Stack Overflow and something the founders have explicitly defined as 'OK'.  There is even a badge for it (with 3 up votes): [The Self Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) Badge

Answer (score 6):

Don't delete your question.

If someone else comes along with the same problem as you (however unlikely that might be) they'll see your question and answer and thus they'll be able to solve their problem.

The same thing happened to a couple of my questions on SO. The answers provided suggested a solution that didn't work but led me to the right answer. I posted this (with due credit to the route I took) and accepted the answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765616/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-raised-from-spring-net-on-the-call-to-contextregist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734313/the-columns-property-on-my-wpf-toolkit-datagrid-isnt-set-despite-the-datacontext) if you're interested).